# Changing borderDash for specific gridLines in radar chart

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I am using [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org) to generate a radar chart.

I wish for the last gridLine (the outermost) to remain solid, while all the others are dashed.

Picture example:

[image: adoreboard radar chart on imgur]

I've seen that it is possible to have varying borderDash in [this pull request](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/7471) which also shows an image of it in action but have yet to find a way to script it. (**edit**: it seems that the linked pull request has made it onto master, planned for release with V3.0 - meaning it is not yet available(?))

Quick example code of a script:

```
scale: {
gridLines: {
    borderDash: function(context) {
        return context.index % 2 === 0 ? [2, 3] : [10, 10];
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can already use **Chart.js version 3**, it's available as [Chart.js 3.0.0-beta](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta).

Simply add the following `script` tag to your `HTML` page.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-beta/chart.min.js"></script>
```

Please take a look at the following code snippet and see how it works.

```js
new Chart("radar-chart", {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [25.48, 54.16, 7.61, 8.06, 4.45],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        min: 0,
        max: 60,
        stepSize: 10
      },
      gridLines: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        color: "lightgreen",
        borderDash: context => context.index == 6 ? [] : [6, 4]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-beta/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="radar-chart" height="120"></canvas>
```